# How to get params value based on specific label?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, sinatra

I am parsing JSON and passing it as `fields_array` to render an `erb` template. This is a Sinatra app.

I have:

```
private

def fields_params
  # example of parsed JSON, Company Name sometimes is Field6 but sometimes Field3
  [["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]  
end

def company_name
  # I want to return company name from params[company_field_id]
  # Maybe something like:
  id = fields_params.select{|field| field[0] == "Company Name" }.flatten[1]
  params[id]
end

def fields_array
  fields_params.collect do |label, param_id| 
    { label: label, value: params[param_id] } if params[param_id]
  end
end
```

How should I get `company_name` from `params`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]` is a commonly seen data pattern, and, once you recognize it you'll know it can easily be coerced into a Hash:

```
hash = Hash[[["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]]
```

Here's what it looks like now:

```
{
    "Company Name" => "Field6",
           "Email" => "Field5"
}
```

At that point, it's easy to get the value:

```
hash['Company Name']
=> "Field6"
```

So, I'd modify your code to return a hash, making it a lot easier to retrieve values:

```
def fields_params
  # example of parsed JSON, Company Name sometimes is Field6 but sometimes Field3
  Hash[ [["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]] ]
end
```

A lot of the time the JSON I see is already going to result in a Hash of some sort after parsing. Without seeing your input JSON I can't say for sure, but it could already be in that format, and something you're doing is turning it into an array of arrays, which is what a hash looks like if run through `map` or `collect` or has had `to_a` applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [find method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

```
fields_params.find{|x| x.first == "Company Name"}.last # => "Field6"
```